# storing Socket.io open sockets' ids in a MySQL db

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

** **Problem:**

For a social media app (think of Facebook), it's necessary to have a **real-time notification system**, For that I came across many options including how Facebook itself handles it; which's by using the old **long polling** hack. I would like instead to use **Socket.io**, but the simple implementations that I found on the internet involve systems where you broadcast to all users or users in (say: some chat rooms);

** **Suggested solution**:

for my case I thought of handling it in the following manner:

1. The user connects to the app, a new socket/connection is established and the relative **socket id** is stored in a MySQL **(user_id, socket_id) 'open_sockets' table**.
2. When a user - (say: likes a post), it automatically registers him as a subscriber in a MySQL **(post_id, user_id) 'subscriptions' table**.
3. Now, when the post gets updated by someone else replying or liking it..etc, I query all the subscribers' ids from the aforementioned 'subscriptions' table, and then query their relative socket_id from 'open_sockets' table.
4. I **broadcast** to clients with the retrieved socket ids.

This system could get complicated (in nature and requirements), it involves communicating with the database to retrieve the right socket ids.

** **questions:**

1. What do you think about this solution?
2. What could be the best way to handle such a scenario (for example: in a Facebook like platform)?

Comment: I'm not sure Stack Overflow is the right place for this question, since it is more about design than about programming, but I'm not sure which site if any would be appropriate. (Maybe [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)? Don't take my word for it). Your plan is similiar on the surface to something I am currently designing, but with additional factors: you'll eventually scale to multiple servers terminating sockets, and you'll probably need to handle clients that (re?)connect shortly *after* a message is sent that they should have received, but missed, for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you for commenting on. it's my bad estimation that this is perhaps not the place. As for the time being I would like to go with my design for a single server and scale up horizontally when necessary. As for reconnecting, now surely, the notification is going to be stored somewhere in the db. hence when the user reconnects I could simply send him whatever ""unseen"" notifications there are.

Comment: @Profess Physics did you follow above approach or other?